# Error func.apply is not a function error in react native

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I am trying to create a react native app for the first time and I get this weird error that I can't understand. this is my code :

```
update_signals = () => {
    url = this.state.url + "action=get_signals"
    fetch(url).then((response) => {
    /** handling the response */
        object = response.text()
        if (typeof object === "undefined"){}else{
            setTimeout(object.
            then((text) => {
            /** handling the text */
            this.get_signals_form_response(text)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
            /** some problem with getting text from response */
            alert("some error : " + error.message)
            })
            ,10000)
        }
    })
    /** this catch is for total reject */
    .catch((error) => {
        alert("total error : " + error.message)
    })
}
```

I click the button to see this work and after a few times of clicking the button and after working fine for the first a few times I get this error.

```
func.apply is not a function. In "func.apply(undefined,args)" func.apply is undefined
```

You can see the image in here :

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKr8r.png)

Even when I Put it between try and catch block It doesn't handle it as an error.

Comment: You seem to be calling `setTimeout` on something that is not a function.

Comment: But object.text() is a function. Even i check if it is undefined or not but still. Plus why try and catch won't handle this?

Comment: `object.then((text) => { whatever })` is undefined, since the last function doesn't return anything

Comment: Saved my life here. I have trying to figure out this crash in my react-native app for more than 2 months. Today i resolved this issue.